# Why only got small part of null point exception stack

Tags: java

I got NullPointException from below place.

```
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
```

Because I user ThreadPoolExecutor, and get Exception in this thread method. And then I have other method which override afterExecute:

```
   @Override
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
```

And I call other method in afterExecute:

```
    T result = future.get();
```

This method will cause null point exception:

My question is that.
When first several times, I get exception. I can see the exception's fully log.
But after that, I only can see small part of this exception:

1st several times:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.execution.AbstractExecutionUnit.getResult(AbstractExecutionUnit.java:93)
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.execution.AbstractExecutionUnit.afterExecute(AbstractExecutionUnit.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:888)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(BetRadarCache.java:134)
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.execution.OMDataModelServiceImpl$10.call(OMDataModelServiceImpl.java:1010)
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.execution.OMDataModelServiceImpl$10.call(OMDataModelServiceImpl.java:999)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    ... 2 more
```

After that:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.execution.AbstractExecutionUnit.getResult(AbstractExecutionUnit.java:93)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.execution.AbstractExecutionUnit.afterExecute(AbstractExecutionUnit.java:153)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:888)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Why the log is different? I really appreciate if someone can explain the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an optimization in the JVM. After throwing the same exception several times and printing the stacktrace, it optimizes and prints truncated stacktrace.

It is mentioned in the [Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/relnotes-139183.html)

> The compiler in the server VM now provides correct stack backtraces for all "cold" built-in exceptions. For performance purposes, when such an exception is thrown a few times, the method may be recompiled. After recompilation, the compiler may choose a faster tactic using preallocated exceptions that do not provide a stack trace. **To disable completely the use of preallocated exceptions, use this new flag: -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow.**

Comment: Thanks for you explain. That's helpful.